# KendoUI and Angular2 UpgradeAdapter

Tags: kendo-ui, angular

I realize that Telerik has posted a roadmap to releasing an Angular 2 version for Kendo UI.  That's awesome, however; our company has already begun developing using Angular 2 and our release map is not inline with Telerik's.  One strategy we are considering is to use KendoUI Angular 1 directives and the Angular 2 UpgradeAdapter.  This will enable us to use Angular 1 directives inside of a Angular 2 implementation.

Has anyone used the UpgradeAdapter to leverage Kendo UI Angular 1 directives inside of Angular 2 using upgradeNg1Component?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered PrimeNG UI library for Angular2? It is purely for Angular2. http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/

Comment: I'm evaluating primeng.  We have a pretty heavy requirements on grid and chart capabilities.  Thx for the link.

Comment: After trying several different approaches to leveraging Telerik such as creating a component using jQuery and ElementRef, using the KendoValueAccessor approach (http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/integration/angular2) I decided not to use Telerik due to the long roadmap.  Looked at PrimeNg which is great but decided on wijmo.